# Ejecutar varios update nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Hola por motivos de versiones del servidor, tengo que trabjar con ecs5, tengo el siguiente codigo que recibe una lista que debe actualizar en varias colleciones, pero solo me actualiza el ultimo update, estoy comenzando y no consigo el error, se que debe ser con los resolve, pero no se que pudiese ser, aca el codigo:

```
        var actualizaTodo = function (elemento) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                TransbankAcuerdos.update({ _id: elemento.idAcuerdo }, { $set: { producto_id: elemento.idProductoOriginal } }, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("ocurrio un error")
                        reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                    } else  {
                        console.log("actualizo acuerdo " , elemento.idAcuerdo)
                        User.update({ _id: elemento._user }, { $pull: { propiedades: { promociones: { $exists: true } } } }, function (err ) {

                            if (err) {
                                console.log("ocurrio un error")
                                reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                            }
                            else  {                             
                                console.log("actualizo usuario " , elemento.iduser)       
                                Promociones.updateOne({ _id: elemento.idPromo }, { $set: { estado: false } }, function (err) {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.log("ocurrio un error")
                                        reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                                    } else  {
                                        console.log("actualizo promociones " + elemento.idPromo)
                                        resolve();
                                  }
                                }) 
                            } 
                        })  
                    } 
                })
              }

            )

        }
```

disculpen los errores estoy comenzando, de antemano gracias....

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que concatenes las promesas, es mucho mas fácil de esa manera y te ahorras el `callback hell`

Los modelos de mongoose y mongodb devuelven promesas, no hace falta pasar un callback

Sería de la siguiente manera

```javascript
function myFunction() {
  return Model.find(...)
    .then(r1 => Model2.updateOne(...))
    .then(r2 => Model3.updateMany(...))
    .then(r3 => {
       return myFunctionResult 
    })
}
```